# serial number changing next to next page in pagnation

Tags: php

I need serial number next to next page, first page from 1 to 10, next from 11 to 20...... but my code prints 1 to 10 for all pages.

```
<?php

    if (isset($_GET['pageno'])) {
        $pageno = $_GET['pageno'];
    } else {
        $pageno = 1;
    }
    $number = 1;
    $no_of_records_per_page = 10;
    $offset = ($pageno-1) * $no_of_records_per_page;
    $total_pages_sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM regs";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$total_pages_sql);
    $total_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)[0];
    $total_pages = ceil($total_rows / $no_of_records_per_page);
    //print_r($total_pages);
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM regs LIMIT $offset, $no_of_records_per_page"); 

    while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        // How many elements per page

        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$res['FirstName']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$res['Email']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$res['Gender']."</td>";
        echo "<td><a href=\"view.php?id=$res[id]\">View</a>  | <a href=\"edit.php?id=$res[id]\">Edit</a> | <a href=\"delete.php?id=$res[id]\" onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')\">Delete</a></td>";

        $pageNumber = isset($_GET['page']) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;
        $currentNumber = ($pageNumber - 1) * $no_of_records_per_page + $number;
        echo "<td>  ". $currentNumber++ ." </td>";
        $number++;  
    }

?>
```

Comment: You have both `$_GET['pageno']` _and_ `$_GET['page']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code should be like that

```
if (isset($_GET['pageno'])) {
    $pageno = $_GET['pageno'];
} else {
    $pageno = 1;
}
$number = 1;
$no_of_records_per_page = 10;
$offset = ($pageno-1) * $no_of_records_per_page;
$total_pages_sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM regs";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$total_pages_sql);
$total_rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result)[0];
$total_pages = ceil($total_rows / $no_of_records_per_page);
//print_r($total_pages);
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM regs LIMIT $offset, $no_of_records_per_page"); 

while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    // How many elements per page

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$res['FirstName']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$res['Email']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$res['Gender']."</td>";
    echo "<td><a href=\"view.php?id=$res[id]\">View</a>  | <a href=\"edit.php?id=$res[id]\">Edit</a> | <a href=\"delete.php?id=$res[id]\" onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')\">Delete</a></td>";

    $currentNumber = ($pageno - 1) * $no_of_records_per_page + $number;
    echo "<td>  ". $currentNumber++ ." </td>";
    $number++;  
}
```